# How to animate to rotate counter-clockwise

Tags: ios, swift

I have a segmented control and I'd like to animate a UIView to rotate clockwise when the right side of the control is tapped, and counter-clockwise when the left side is tapped. My code to rotate is:

```
func rotateRight() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (0.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 360.0)
    })
```

And then I'm using this code to handle the changes depending on which segment is tapped (Edited for update):

```
    if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.loginRegisterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        rotateLeft()
        // Roll to the left
    } else {
        self.loginRegisterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        rotateRight()
        // Roll to the right
    }
```

So basically in the if conditional I want to call a `rotateLeft()` function - how can I do this?

EDIT: Here's my full code for the animation, including Pierce's suggestion:

```
// Rotation
var viewAngle: CGFloat = 0    // Right-side up to start
let π = CGFloat.pi   // Swift allows special characters hold alt+p to use this, it allows for cleaner code

func rotate(by angle: CGFloat) {

    self.viewAngle += angle

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.viewAngle)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })         

}

lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TTTdude")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotate)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return imageView
}()



lazy var loginRegisterSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["iOS", "Android"])
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = UIColor.black
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()

func handleLoginRegisterChange() {

    let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.loginRegisterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        rotate(by: -2*π)
        // Roll to the left
    } else {
        self.loginRegisterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        rotate(by: 2*π)
        // Roll to the right
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rotate it by whatever angle you did for clockwise, but multiply it by negative one

```
func rotateLeft() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: ((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0) * -1)
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: ((0.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 360.0) * -1)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

I should also mention that when you say `(180.0 * CGFloat(π)) / 180` - You're just saying π, because 180/180 is one.

It looks to me like you're trying to do two different rotations at once? I'm a little confused by that. One thing I've found that really helps is to track the view's axis orientation if you're doing multiple rotations both clockwise and counter-clockwise. Do something like create a property called `viewAngle`

```
var viewAngle: CGFloat = 0    // Right-side up to start
let π = CGFloat.pi   // Swift allows special characters hold alt+p to use this, it allows for cleaner code

func rotate(by angle: CGFloat) {

    for i in 0 ..< 4 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.125, delay: 0.125 * Double(i), options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            self.viewAngle += angle/4
            self.rotateView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.viewAngle)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }        

}
```

If you want to rotate right pass in a positive angle (i.e. π, π/2, π/4, 2*π), or if left pass in a negative angle.

Rotate right by 180 degrees:

```
rotate(by: π)
```

Rotate left by 180 degrees:

```
rotate(by: -π)
```

EDIT: As you were mentioning, which I didn't see until I tried for myself, when you plug in π or 2π whether it's negative or positive, it just rotates clockwise. To get around this I had to make it rotate by -π/4 increments. So to do a full-circle rotate counter clockwise I did a loop of -π/4 animations if that makes sense. It works, but I feel like there should be an easier way to do this. I would appreciate anyone else chiming in.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you use 180 * π / 180 ? That's just π

Comment: Thanks, that was nice and simple - however I've replaced the conditional ('if'` has `rotateLeft()` and `else` has `rotateRight()`), but there is no change to the animation when I tap the left or right segments, it always rotates clockwise.

Comment: if you want to rotate counter clockwise by 180 degrees just say `view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -π)`

Comment: @KingTim - I'm also somewhat confused by what you're doing. You're telling it to do two different rotations at once.

Comment: it's quick and dirty, this is my first time animating with code - just used a quick tutorial.. the first `CGAffineTransform` line only rotated it 180 so I added the second line.

Comment: so there is no way to have the view rotate clockwise 360 with one function, then counterclockwise 360 with another function (that I can call depending on the selected segment)? Or is it just my dumb code holding me back here...

Comment: @KingTim - Please see my updated answer. You can do it all with one function. You can change the direction just by the angle you pass in whether it's positive or negative

Comment: Thanks, that looks like an awesome way to do this - I changed my code (I edited my question to show the full updated code) but what happens now is I tap on the right segment, and the image rotates 180 (ends up upside down). Then I tap on the left segment and it rotates 180 again (back to right side up). i.e. never counter-clockwise

Comment: @KingTim - well think about it - you're rotating it 180 degrees to the right, and then back 180 degrees to the left which is directly to it's original orientation. If you rotate it 180 degrees to the right, and then want to go 180 degrees from the ORIGINAL orientation , you'll then have to rotate 360 degrees from where you're at or 2π

Comment: @KingTim  - Actually I should say -2π from where you are at.

Comment: Still no luck - tried using `2*π` and `-2*π` but now the image doesn't rotate at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134707/discussion-between-pierce-and-kingtim).

Comment: Great answer, thanks @Pierce! I modded below for a more wholesome re-useable approach.

Answer (score 0):

**(swift 4)**

it will rotate 180 degree counter clock wise

```
 self.viewRoatate.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:  CGFloat.pi / -2)
            self.viewRoatate.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:  CGFloat.pi)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func rotate(button: UIButton, time: Double, overlap: Double, clockWise: Bool) {
var angles = [CGFloat(Double.pi), CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2]
if !clockWise {
    angles = [CGFloat(Double(270) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(180) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(90) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(0) * .pi/180)]
}
for i in 0..<angles.count {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: time, delay: time - overlap * Double(i), animations: {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angles[i])
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using **CABasicAnimation**:
**left-rotation**(counter-clockwise: **-360**) & **right-rotation**(clockwise: **360**)

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
animation.toValue = direction == .left ? -2 * (CGFloat.pi) : 2 * CGFloat.pi
animation.duration = 1
button.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```